# Kusto query to get list if IP address whitelisted in Azure Storage account

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-log-analytics

I need to get list of IP address whitelisted in Azure storage account using Azure log analytics.

Are there any table in Azure Log analytics which stores this information.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Log analytics is for Log and Audit data. It does not store information about the resource configuration.

For this you can either call the Azure Resource Manager API directly, use Azure Policy to Audit or limit the usage or use Azure Resource Graph

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/resource-graph/overview

I am not that well in Kusto. But if you expand the properties of Azure Storage you should be able to get the IP addresses

```
Resources
| where type =~ 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts'
```